# How to prevent Terminal.app from closing when ssh is running?

Tags: mac, ssh, terminal, terminal.app

Usually if a program is running in Terminal.app, when you try to close it it will give you a warning "Do you want to close this Window?" This happens to almost everything that I have tried, including more, man, bash, etc. It gives you this warning even if you have suspended jobs.

The only exception is ssh. I can ssh into another machine and accidentally click the close button and Terminal.app would be happy to close it for me. Are there ways to change this behavior? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to explicitly remove SSH from the permitted-to-close processes list in Terminal's preferences:

[image: Terminal preferences]

Comment: oh... that's easy, thanks! I don't understand this default setting though...

Comment: It's the default presumably because most people consider that list of programs to be like shells, and killing shells without prompting is desirable to a number of users. But that does mean users have to beware about closing a terminal while there are remote processes running, since Terminal only knows about local processes. A number of `ssh` users typically start a `screen` session to keep the remote processes alive, so closing the `ssh` connection has no adverse consequences in this regard.

Comment: If you think the default should be different, as always, consider telling Apple. You can send a bug report (requires a free developer account) http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ or use http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html .